# Were Cylon Centurions ever given individual designations?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

Was there ever any instance of Cylon centurions in the Original Series having distinct individual designations (or names)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the episode "Sage of a Star World" there is a Centurion named Serpentine who is commanded by the imperious leader.
http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Saga_of_a_Star_World

Additionally there was Red Eye which the people on Equellus called the Cylon and then in Galactica 1980 there was Centuri and Cy who were other Centurions with designated names.

http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Centurion_%28TOS%29

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot. i wanted to name a character in something i'd made and hadn't found anything when i posted. cheers.

Answer (score 4):

In both the episode "The Gun on Ice Planet Zero" and its novelization ("The Cylon Death Machine" by Robert Thurston), the gold command centurion is referred to as Vulpa.